# Oracle Data Provider for .NET : "Connection Lifetime" - significance of 0?

Tags: windows, oracle, odp.net

Feel like I should be able to find this in the documentation but I can't (eg : http://docs.oracle.com/html/E10927_01/featConnecting.htm)

By default the "Connection Lifetime" is set to zero. What's the significance of zero ? Sometimes an argument of zero means "for ever" - is that the case here ? If it truly were zero seconds it seems like a strange default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK well I found this information which provides an answer. On https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719767%28v=vs.71%29.aspx it says against "Connection Lifetime" ...

> When a connection is returned to the pool, its creation time is
>   compared with the current time, and the connection is destroyed if
>   that time span (in seconds) exceeds the value specified by Connection
>   Lifetime. This is useful in clustered configurations to force load
>   balancing between a running server and a server just brought online.
>
> A value of zero (0) will cause pooled connections to have the maximum
>   time-out.

So the answer does seem to be that zero will provide a "long" lifetime (as opposed to a zero length one) but what "long" will be depends, I assume, upon other machine configuration values.

BTW that link is tagged with ".NET Framework 1.1" so, obviously, rather old information but given the nature of the topic I wouldn't expect that to have changed in any significant way in the time elapsed.

Comment: I found the information "When a connection is returned to the pool, its creation time is compared with the current time, and the connection is destroyed if that time span (in seconds) exceeds the value specified by Connection Lifetime" useful because the key here is that the connection had to have been returned to the pool first, for the Connection-Lifetime value to be compared against, to take action. The app I am troubleshooting doesn't release/close the connections to begin with so Connection-Lifetime value of any value is of no use.